# Php-amqplib/rabbitmq-bundle consumer dont shut down

Tags: php, symfony, rabbitmq

I use this configuration of php-amqplib/rabbitmq-bundle, in my Symfony 4. But **stat** consumer dont shut down after 29min 50sec, how fix it?

```
batch_consumers:
    stat:
        connection: default
        exchange_options:
            name: stat-exchange
            type: direct
        queue_options:
            name: stat-queue
        callback: StatConsumer
        qos_options:
            prefetch_count: 100
        graceful_max_execution:
            timeout: 1790 # 29min 50sec
```

Comment: Seems an open bug https://github.com/php-amqplib/RabbitMqBundle/issues/550 But a PR for fix it is already submitted

Comment: Please test using `php-amqplib` version `v2.8.2-rc1`